# Stomp 1.2 ActiveMQ 5.15 - ACK received without a ack id for acknowledge

Tags: c, activemq-classic, stomp

I have built a c function that should read from an ActiveMQ via stomp library.  This code is reading an additional MESSAGE prior to the RECEIPT (which is what I would expect). Please advise on why my RECEIPT frame is not coming prior to a second MESSAGE frame. Also please note that I am wrapping this code with BEGIN and COMMIT frames which may or may not be best practice.

Thanks in advance.

```
int receive_from_queue_ack( MQDEF *mqdef, int transaction ) {
    apr_status_t rc;
    stomp_frame frame_write;
    stomp_frame* frame_read = NULL;
    char transaction_str[37];
    char* ack = NULL;
    char* protocol = NULL;
    char* receipt_id = NULL;
    char* message_id = NULL;
    char* message = NULL;
    char* seq = NULL;
    uuid_t uuid;
    char receipt_id_begin_uuid[37];
    char receipt_id_commit_uuid[37];
    char receipt_id_ack_uuid[37];
    char id_uuid[37];
    int receipt_flag = 1;

    uuid_generate_random(uuid);
    uuid_unparse_lower(uuid, transaction_str);

    uuid_generate_random(uuid);
    uuid_unparse_lower(uuid, receipt_id_begin_uuid);

    uuid_generate_random(uuid);
    uuid_unparse_lower(uuid, id_uuid);

    uuid_generate_random(uuid);
    uuid_unparse_lower(uuid, receipt_id_commit_uuid);


    uuid_generate_random(uuid);
    uuid_unparse_lower(uuid, receipt_id_ack_uuid);

    fprintf(stdout, "1) *** Transaction BEGIN - (receive_from_queue)\n");
    frame_write.command = "BEGIN";
    frame_write.headers = apr_hash_make((apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "transaction", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, transaction_str); 
    frame_write.body_length = -1;
    frame_write.body = NULL;
    rc = stomp_write(mqdef->amqConnection, &frame_write, (apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    if ( rc != APR_SUCCESS ) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    printf("3) Subscribe begin\n");
    frame_write.command = "SUBSCRIBE";
    frame_write.headers = apr_hash_make((apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "destination", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, mqdef->queueName);
    apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "ack", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, "client");
    apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, "client-123");
    apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "activemq.prefetchSize", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, "1");
    frame_write.body_length = -1;
    frame_write.body = NULL;
    rc = stomp_write(mqdef->amqConnection, &frame_write, (apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    if ( rc != APR_SUCCESS ) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    frame_read = NULL;
    rc = stomp_read(mqdef->amqConnection, &frame_read, (apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    if ( rc != APR_SUCCESS ) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    ack = NULL;
    if( frame_read != NULL && strncmp(frame_read->command, "MESSAGE", 7) == 0 ) {
        ack = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "ack", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        printf("5) ack=<%s>\n", ack);
        if( ack == NULL ) {
            printf("ack being null is a problem\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        message_id = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "message-id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        printf("5) message_id=<%s>\n", message_id);
        printf("5) command=<%s>, body=<%s>\n", frame_read->command, frame_read->body);
    } else if( frame_read != NULL && strncmp(frame_read->command, "ERROR", 5) == 0 ) {
        message_id = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "message-id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        printf("5) message_id=<%s>\n", message_id);
        printf("5) command=<%s>, body=<%s>\n", frame_read->command, frame_read->body);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        message_id = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "message-id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        printf("5) message_id=<%s>\n", message_id);
        printf("5) command=<%s>, body=<%s>\n", frame_read->command, frame_read->body);
        printf("5) should never get here.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    frame_write.command = "ACK";
    frame_write.headers = apr_hash_make((apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "transaction", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, transaction_str);
    apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, ack);
    apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "receipt-id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, receipt_id_ack_uuid);
    printf("set id =<%s>\n", ack);
    frame_write.body_length = -1;
    frame_write.body = NULL;
    rc = stomp_write(mqdef->amqConnection, &frame_write, (apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    if ( rc != APR_SUCCESS ) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    frame_read = NULL;
    rc = stomp_read(mqdef->amqConnection, &frame_read, (apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    if ( rc != APR_SUCCESS ) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    if( frame_read != NULL && strncmp(frame_read->command, "RECEIPT", 7) == 0 ) {
        message_id = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "message-id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        receipt_id = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "receipt-id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        printf("7) receipt-id=<%s>\n", receipt_id);
        printf("7) message-id=<%s>\n", message_id);
        printf("7) command=<%s>, body=<%s>\n", frame_read->command, frame_read->body);
    } else if( frame_read != NULL && strncmp(frame_read->command, "ERROR", 5) == 0 ) {
        message_id = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "message_id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        receipt_id = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "receipt-id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        printf("7) receipt-id=<%s>\n", receipt_id);
        printf("7) message-id=<%s>\n", message_id);
        printf("7) command=<%s>, body=<%s>\n", frame_read->command, frame_read->body);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        message_id = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "message_id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        printf("7) message-id=<%s>\n", message_id);
        printf("7) command=<%s>, body=<%s>\n", frame_read->command, frame_read->body);
        ack = (char*) apr_hash_get(frame_read->headers, "ack", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING);
        printf("5) ack=<%s>\n", ack);
        printf("this is a failure\n");
        frame_write.command = "ACK";
        frame_write.headers = apr_hash_make((apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
        apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "transaction", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, transaction_str);
        apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, ack);
        apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "receipt-id", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, receipt_id_ack_uuid);
        rc = stomp_write(mqdef->amqConnection, &frame_write, (apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
        if ( rc != APR_SUCCESS ) {
            return FAILURE;
        }
    }

    frame_write.command = "COMMIT";
    frame_write.headers = apr_hash_make((apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "transaction", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, transaction_str);
    frame_write.body_length = -1;
    frame_write.body = NULL;
    rc = stomp_write(mqdef->amqConnection, &frame_write, (apr_pool_t *)mqdef->pool);
    if ( rc != APR_SUCCESS ) {
        return FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "12) *** Transaction Complete - (receive_from_queue)\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct STOMP header in the acknowledge to indicate the ACK ID so the broker is telling you that you did it wrong.  The STOMP specification is a good place to start to learn what to put in each performative, in this case the header is "id" and not "message-id"

As usual with C code it is quite hard to read so reformating your code above with some comments or context would be helpful but so far I don't see where the client code takes the "ack" header from the incoming messages and transfers it to the actual 'ACK' frame so that could be the issue.

From the spec:

> If the message is received from a subscription that requires explicit acknowledgment (either client or client-individual mode) then the MESSAGE frame MUST also contain an ack header with an arbitrary value. This header will be used to relate the message to a subsequent ACK or NACK frame.

Refer to the [STOMP specification](http://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#ACK) to learn more

Comment: When I change the message-id to id per the spec, then I see the following exception. command=<ERROR>, body=<org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: Unexpected ACK received for message-id [null], this may be related to another issue. I am going to reinstall my activemq instance and try again.

Comment: As you can see below, you can seed the id is coming back as 12345 as from Message header, however when I try and consume the message it is saying null.

Response: command=<MESSAGE>, body_length=<26>
msgid=<ID\ccentos7-40511-1529417659914-3\c6\c-1\c1\c10>
id=<12345>
ACK
COMMIT
Transaction Complete
INFO: pre-read
Response: command=<ERROR>, body=<org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.ProtocolException: Unexpected ACK received for message-id [null]

Comment: Sounds like your code is doing something wrong, maybe spend some time understanding the spec, then analyze the code?

Comment: Agree, I am going back to the stomp 1.2 spec and using netcat to send the actual STOMP commands and see the results. Once that is figured out then I will put it into my c program. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps referring to some STOMP unit tests that show the frames will help: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-stomp/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/Stomp12Test.java

Comment: Tim, your advice has been helpful. I feel I am starting to get a better understanding of the Stomp protocol. I have spent the last 2 days working on my subscribe function however when I introduce ACKs with RECEIPTs I am receiving a second MESSAGE response prior to my RECEIPT ACK. I feel a little stuck and could use some furhther advice. Thanks.

Comment: Most likely culprit is message prefetching, configure a prefetch of 1 to avoid this.

Comment: In my subscribe I have set the prefetch to 1 per the documentation that I viewed earlier. -- apr_hash_set(frame_write.headers, "activemq.prefetchSize", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, "1". Let me know if you have other thoughts as to where to focus. Thanks.

Comment: I tried switching from Active MQ 5.15.4 to Apollo 1.17 and once I did that with no code change the code works perfectly (one message at a time). Not sure why. Ideally I would like to understand, but I will consider switching from ActiveMQ to Apollo as I need to use STOMP in my application. I really appreciate the help I have received on this topic.

Comment: Apollo is dead software that is not supported or maintained in any way

Comment: OK, I will avoid Apollo.